# Strange display issue occurring after a prior Internal disk error

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

One day I started my computer, it opened regularly, but the crashed, reading: "Internal disk error".

I had encountered this problem before, and it turned out to be due to a faulty hard drive, but now I have a new one (about 3 months old).
When I restarted my computer, it opened regularly, and the login chime played, but all I saw was a black screen with a mouse pointer on it. I could move it around, and after playing around a bit, I decided to try putting in my password to a nonexistent box. I typed it, pressed enter, and there was my regular background.

Nothing else. 
Just a background.

I right clicked, and I was able to create a new folder. I could see the folder and a background now. That is all I could see. I opened the folder, and I clicked desktop, and all my regular files were there, but I couldn't see them.
I tried to open one, and it opened. But I couldn't see the program.
I only knew because of the login chime. later, I restarted my computer, and a notification popped up. I could tell because of a noise and a slight greying of the screen. I pressed enter. 
The box went away.
That's all the information I have.

Computer model:

ASUS aspire AX1930-ES30P
Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing control-alt-delete. If the task manager pops up you could try starting explorer.exe. Can you use it in [Safe Mode?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7). There might be a graphics driver you need to install. It would be on a disk that came with your computer or from [This website](http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/acer/laptops-desktops/ax1930/13530)